# How to make donut chart clickable

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Ignore the english mistakes. I want to make donut chart clickable. If i click on one slice it should take towards next page(like url(a href).
I have tried to code. but this is only for highlight bar.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Click points to go to URL'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      cursor: 'pointer',
      point: {
        events: {
          click: function() {
            location.href = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' +
              this.options.key;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [{
      y: 29.9,
      name: 'USA',
      key: 'United_States'
    }, {
      y: 71.5,
      name: 'Canada',
      key: 'Canada'
    }, {
      y: 106.4,
      name: 'Mexico',
      key: 'Mexico'
    }]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: Not sure how good your English is, but saying *please provide the code its urgent* doesn't sound very respectful.

Comment: your snippet doesn't work. Please provide a usable example of the problem. You need to include HighCharts from a CDN, for a start. And "please provide the code it's urgent" makes it sound like you think your time is more important than ours. We are volunteers, please respect that.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read the help section on how to ask a question, you at least need to try yourself and then ask for help when/if you need it - this shows no effort whatsoever

Comment: @Kitty You want a donut chart, but why using `type: 'column'` then?

Comment: sorry all. I respect your time.I am newbie to charts. above code i have used for highlight chart as same i need to make for donut charts. I dont know how to do that so asked here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`chart: { type: 'pie' }`](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/pie-chart) with `innerSize: '50%'` to create a donut.

Here is an example:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Click points to go to URL'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      innerSize: '50%',
      cursor: 'pointer',
      point: {
        events: {
          click: function() {
            location.href = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' +
              this.options.key;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    
    data: [{
      y: 29.9,
      name: 'USA',
      key: 'United_States'
    }, {
      y: 71.5,
      name: 'Canada',
      key: 'Canada'
    }, {
      y: 106.4,
      name: 'Mexico',
      key: 'Mexico'
    }]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

Highcharts has a very [good documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie), so I advise you to read it first so you will be able to answer such questions by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

give an id to the  of the donut chart and then use jquery or javascript function for the klick event

like so:

```
<div id="clickme" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:black;">

</div>

$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  location.href = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/';
});
```